# Is it possible to COUNT the CONDITION and including NULL as well as the other values as 0?

Tags: sqlite, count

I have a problem. It includes the condition that to COUNT the rows where its status = 1 (GROUP BY name).

However, the result should include the rows WHERE those are not = 1 and NULL. And they are counted as 0.

I have tried cte, CASE WHEN, WHERE status = 1 or status IS NULL. It does include null as 0, but there are name containing 1 and 0 or only containing 0.

If I use WHERE status IS NULL OR status=1, the name with status 0 is not counted.

If I use CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN 0

```
          WHEN status IS 0 THEN 0

          WHEN status = 1 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT name)
```

Then the name containing 1 AND 0 will be counted as 0.

TABLE:

INSERT INTO
students
(name, student_id, exercise_id, status)
VALUES
(Uolevi, 1, 1, 0),
(Uolevi, 1, 1, 0),
(Uolevi, 1, 1, 1),
(Uolevi, 1, 2, 0),
(Uolevi, 1, 2, 0),
(Uolevi, 1, 2, 1),
(Maija , 2, 1, 1),
(Maija , 2, 2, 1),
(Maija , 2, 2, 1),
(Maija , 2, 2, 1),
(Maija , 2, 3, 0),
(Juuso , 3, 1, 0),
(Juuso , 3, 2, 0),
(Juuso , 3, 3, 0),
(Miiko , NULL, NULL, NULL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this.

```
SELECT  s.name, COUNT(DISTINCT exercise_id)
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN transmissions t
ON s.id=t.student_id
AND state = 1
group by student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED since you specified your expected result.
You can add a FILTER clause to the aggregate function COUNT() to only count the rows matched by the filter:

```
SELECT name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT exercise_id) FILTER (WHERE status=1) as exercise_count
FROM students
GROUP BY student_id
ORDER BY exercise_count DESC
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/78_m7-3j) is a fiddle with the values you provided

My query doesn't take into account the table `transmissions` you used in your answer because you didn't specify it's structure or what it does contain, but you can adapt the answer to your real needs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help.


I forgot to specify clearly the TABLE, please take a look my edited post.


I have to use DISTINCT here to not include the duplicated values. Sum here does count every value where status = 1, 0, or NULL.


The expected result is:
(Uolevi, 2), (Maija, 2),(Juuso,0), (Miiko,0)

Comment: @FCChelsea Modified the answer after you made clear what you needed.